# Searching a function expressing $\sin x$ versus $\cos x$

Tags: functions

I'm searching a specific function, I searched everywhere and didn't find anything. Here is my problem with $X=\cos x$ I'm trying to find $f(X)= \sin x$, so that this function shall use only $ \cos x$ as variable.
Can someone help me?
If you think that ain't achievable let me know it!

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for your answers but they are incorrect,let me explain. Everyone knows that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ the issue is that $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ is not equal to $\sin x$ but the absolute value of $\sin x$. By another means I've already found such a result. So the question remains.

So the main trouble is now to express using exclusively $\cos x $ as a variable the sign function of $\sin x $ which seems for me very difficult and the reason why I'm asking for assistance.

Let me clarify i'm not asking how to change sinus into cosine but if anyone knows a special function that does.

Once again Thanks by advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. It's confusing because you're using $x$ and $X$. Would you please clarify?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Pythagorean Identity, $ \ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 \ $ ?

Comment: Maybe this relation : $\sin(x)=\cos(x -\pi /2)$ might be helpful too.

Comment: Just curious--what prompted this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function. As Amire Bendjeddou mentioned, about the best you can get is $\sin x = \cos(\tfrac\pi2-x)$.

The problem is that the sine and cosine functions can't be calculated purely from each other. For example, $$\sin 0 = \sin \pi$$ but $$\cos 0 \ne \cos \pi.$$ Similarly, $$\cos\frac\pi 2 = \cos\frac{3\pi}2,$$ but $$\sin \frac\pi 2 \ne \sin\frac{3\pi}2.$$

Comment: i wasn't hoping for a simple way to solve this but i was wondering if a special function had for propriety to transform sinus into cosine, as the Lambert function turns $xln(x)$ into $x$.

Comment: No, you can't do this. The problem is that, for any one value of $\cos x$, there may be more than one value of $\sin x$ (e.g. $x = \pi/2, 3\pi/2$ have the same $\cos$ but different $\sin$, so $\sin$ cannot be purely a function of $\cos$). If you restrict your attention to $0\leq x < \pi/2$, you can do it as in Amire's answer. (There is also no way of turning $x\ln x$ into $x$ either, unless you work with a restricted range. For example, when $x\ln x = 0.1$, $x$ could be $\approx 0.894$ or $\approx 0.028$.)

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x)= + \sqrt{1-X^2 } \ \  \vee \ \   -\sqrt{1-X^2 }$

where $X:=\cos(x)$ , as you defined it.